# How reduce the execution time of JavaScript on Adsense script

Tags: javascript, google-adsense

sorry for my English.. my knowledge for Server Site is very simple...

All my Site has on `<head>` this,

```
<title>my title</title>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="FGjRTf5f-SVBo6y3pl1o0bssstKSUHaW7fmCbuj311bJkQH765" />   

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<link rel="preload" href="CSS/style.css" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="CSS/media.css" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" as="script">
```

than have on my  `<body>` Tag, all **adsense** Script's.

I test a Site of my Website with **pagespeed**, was the test to say for Mobil

[image: was the test to say for Mobil]

On **Reduce the execution time of JavaScript** section, to come this,
[image]

On the Site from my Server, I have **Compress all Content**

[image]

Also, test my Site with **webpagetest.org**, and to come to this [Window](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/191128_K2_36bb7b4d0c728c3586e742f983c88127/1/breakdown/)

My question, how can prevent the **adsense** Script's slowing my Website.

Can Please anyone help me and easy words explain how to resolve this problem, Thanks!

Comment: You are using Google adsense to show ads right? That script is the google adsense script.

Comment: sorry not Understand you...,if you asked me I using `adsense`script, yes

Comment: Try to move the adsense script before your closing </body> tag

Comment: Thanks, I do it, but nothing to change...

Comment: Then I suggest taliking with Google. Please have in mind that implementing adsense is normal to have 1-3 seconds more on page full render.